# luaJit how to free char* data returned from c function

Tags: garbage-collection, ffi, luajit

here is the C function I want to call:

```
char* decrypt(const char* str, int len) {
    char* endata = malloc(len/2);
    //assign
    return endata;
}
```

---

here is lua content:

```
local ffi = require "ffi"
local rsa = ffi.load("test.so")

ffi.cdef[[
char* decrypt(const char* str, int len);
]]

local str = "256b5740ed16e5b15146816f77b0ab74de43d58ab367e9ac850642514f5cc4880e899a6a7775aa"
local c_str = test.decrypt(str, 256)
local lua_str = ffi.string(c_str, 128)
```

would luajit free c_str automaticly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> would luajit free c_str automaticly?

No, it would not.
LuaJIT knows nothing what this pointer is.

Comment: Thanks, I should use ffi.gc to register finalizer, and then LuaJIT  will call finalizer automaticly, like ffi.gc(c_str, ffi.c.free)